# Why am I being held accountable for my karma in this or next life?

Tags: karma, rebirth

If I am not the doer, I am in control of Triguna Sattva, Rajas and Tamas, and these Gunas fashion the work I do, and if whatever I will do in my life is already predefined.

**Then why am I accused of my Karmas?** Why do I have to pay for the Punyas or Paapas of my Karma, when everything is already decided by Lord, is fashioned by the three Gunas, and when Lord is the doer.

Comment: Welcome! Please be clear what you are asking. The body is clear right now. Please modify the question and use proper tags.

Comment: Your actions are not predetermined completely, you possess freewill.

Comment: All answers of your quetions has been given in Bhagwat Geeta. You can either read it [here](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-02-03.html) or you can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3-kuBvDzWU). Both source are totally genuine. If you are not haibutual of reading then go for second option to hear.

Comment: The reason you generate Sanchita and Prarabdha Karma is because you attach yourself to the actions you do. Those actions are destined to happen but attachment or detachment to that action is under your control. If you attach, you have to bear the consequences of such actions - be it good or bad.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria Thank You. Please kindly guide me on how do I detach from the action, how is attachment or detachment from that action under my control

Comment: Actually @Sanjeev it is all because of Aham-Kaara- the '**I**'-ness in us, due of which we feel yourself as 'I' as in I am Sanjeev, I am boy, I am Indian, I am son of my mother, I am devotee of god, I am this that et cetera. This I-ness is the only reason why we have to entertain both Paapa and Punya, and this I-ness never leaves us. But kindly note, I-ness is NOT a negative thing, as it might be sounding. This I-ness is needed to preserve ourselves, I-ness is basis of your doing good to others, and if you build your I-ness in a harmonious way, then only you can attain spiritual bliss.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Thank you! So let us say When everyone sleeps tonight, God eliminates old memories and eliminates  I-ness from everybody in the world. So when all of these billions of minds/bodies wake up tomorrow, what would these minds think? And in few hours, if most minds figure out that the body they are attached to can be physically controlled like lift arms, legs etc- would that create I-ness again? or what would need to happen to determine whether I-ness is created again in the world? Thank you for your advice

Comment: very simple. if you are not the doer of karma, you are also not the receiver of karma. when you stab someone and say 'gunas in my body made me do it', say the same thing when you're put in jail 'gunas in my body are suffering in jail'. If the lord made you do punya, he is also making you get its rewards. Take both together. Or you could go one step further. You could think that you did the punya but only your gunas & body are getting the rewards

Comment: @ram Thank you. For your reference to Gunas, are the Gunas part of brain/body or is it part of soul. For example when the baby embryo is in mom’s belly and life starts, do the Gunas arrive with the soul or are Gunas already part of the embryo body. And when the person dies, is it only soul that leaves or combination of soul and 5 senses and mind. Thank you for your advice and kind helping in understanding this

Comment: Yes @Sanjeev This I-ness is created from the very onset of feeling the self. As soon as a Jeeva thinks it is a separate self, then it gets this Aham-Kaara. In fact the supreme Moksha itself is the state of freedom from the Manas, Buddhi, Ahankaara and Chitta. But as ram told you, if you do not want fruits, then you just devote yourself to lord, and all things will happen like a movie around you. But then would you be able to sustain your life, be it spiritual or material? This is why, we should make our Aham-Kaara Sattvika, so that we may see the real truth of God.

Comment: Sorry I am commenting too much. But do not give heed too much to AhamKara,Manas, Buddhi, et cetera. Paapa and Punya will never cease to exist,never ever, until you attain Moksha.Every Jeeva has to entertain the fruits of each Papa and each Punya, be it small or big. If you have done Punya you have to bear its fruit, and if you have done Paapa, you have to bear its fruits. The play of Karma can never be understood. This is why, you must just be devoted to your IshtaDevata, and ask Him/Her to remove your Vaapas. Remember, our Ishta always takes care of us. ;)

Comment: @ram your examples, metaphors, similes are always very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non attachment is very difficult to achieve. A lot of tapasya is required. Mind and sense control are not very easy. In Kaliyug it is very difficult to do and a good starting point is always doing fasting, doing japa and trying to lead a good life. That is why we always say 'narayanayeti samarpayami' in order to remind us not to develop ego or any other emotion whether negative or positive.

Answer (score 1):

The course of the jiva is preordained. The actions of the jiva are predetermined by the second. But how we react to the situation is left to us. It is the feelings with which we carry out our actions, that determines the further course of the jiva. That is to say, judging the efforts put into achieving a tranquil state of mind, the Lord has the authority to amend the future course of the jiva. We must hence, with this knowledge, refrain from bad thought and deed.